# Impossible to invoke a method ("limit") on an array

Tags: craft3, craft2

I recently upgraded a site from Craft 2 to Craft 3, so I'm trying to figure out what was deprecated and caused this error.

At the top of the page I have this

```
{% set solutions = craft.entries.section('solutions').level(1).all() %}
```

And I'm trying to invoke a dropdown menu like so

```
<li class="nav-item {% if craft.request.segment(1) == 'solutions' %}active{% endif %}">
    {% nav solution in solutions.limit(1) %}
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ solution.url }}">solutions<span class="sr-only">(current)</span> <i class="icon-downarrow"></i> </a>
    {% endnav %}
    <ul class="submenu">
        {% nav solution in solutions %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ solution.url }}">{{ solution.title }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endnav %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

Before I didn't have `.all()` at the end, but only the first menuitem was showing up.
When I added `.all()` in, I get the error `"Impossible to invoke a method ("limit") on an array."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`craft.entries` now returns an [ElementQuery](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/). When you add the `.all()` you're telling Craft to execute the query, which returns an `array` of Elements.

That means that `solutions` is now a simple array, and won't have methods like `.limit(1)` that can be executed on it. It looks like you just want to use the first item in the `solutions` array, so try changing this:

```
      {% nav solution in solutions.limit(1) %}
           <a class="nav-link" href="{{ solution.url }}">solutions<span class="sr-only">(current)</span> <i class="icon-downarrow"></i> </a>
      {% endnav %}
```

To this:

```
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ solutions[0].url }}">solutions<span class="sr-only">(current)</span> <i class="icon-downarrow"></i> </a>
```

More here: [{% nav %} Tags](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/nav.html)